# PS script to make Win11 taskbar icons go to left doesn't work

Tags: powershell, intune

I have written a small script for Intune to execute. If I execute the script manually in PS it works, but executing from Intune doesn't work. Here's the script in question.

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\transcripts\transcript0.txt" -NoClobber
Set-Executionpolicy -Executionpolicy Bypass -force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name "TaskbarAl" -Value 0 -PropertyType Dword -Force
```

The transcript is there for me to easily access the errors if the script doesn't work. Here's the error.

```
Transcript started, output file is C:\transcripts\transcript0.txt
New-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced' because it does 
not exist.
At C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Intune Management Extension\Policies\Scripts\12630a71-8973-4b12-a164-06396862ea3f_0e
4ea086-806a-42e2-9b0e-8e5caf66a7c4.ps1:3 char:1
+ New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersio ...
```

I have added the -PropertyType Dword and I also have attempted to remove the quotes and that's about it.

Comment: I think you accidentally pasted the powershell commands instead of the error

Comment: It looks like that node doesn't exist. You can try debugging it by checking if the higher up nodes exist, like, does HKCU:\SOFTWARE exist? I wonder if Intune is running it in a non-user context that has no user-specific regkeys, just HKLM, not sure if that's a thing

Answer (score 1):

It seems that during a recent update this registry key was moved from HKCU to HKEY_USERS and stored under each user's SID, then read from there.

I threw together a script which worked for me:

```
Set-Executionpolicy -Executionpolicy Bypass -force

$currentusersid = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username |
ForEach-Object { ([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$_).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value }

$regpath = "registry::HKEY_USERS\" + $currentusersid + "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced"

Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath -Name "TaskbarAl" -Value 0 -Force
```

1. Get logged in user's name
2. Translate the name into the SID
3. Store the SID in $currentusersid
4. Use the SID as part of the HKEY_USERS registry path (this isn't defined by PS by default, so using HKU:... won't work) - store this in the $regpath variable

You can then use the full path with the SID to set the value of the key, or create a new one.

NOTES:
I used Set-ItemProperty; I didn't test if the key already exists with value of 1 by default since the change. You may need to run a check to see if the hive/key needs to be created, or just updated.

Obviously this is a user-level fix, Intune may only run it once per device - so if an update reverts this value (like it does with some other things), you'll need to use remediations (if you have the license for it) to check the value of this key periodically for the logged in user - alternatively re-uploading the script as "new" will run the script again.

The obvious down-fall of using remediations is annoying users which manually set and prefer the taskbar to be centered.

Hope that helps!